# Aligning Button to the bottom of CardView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

So I'm creating some CardViews inside a for loop and I want to add a Button to the bottom of each CardView.

I'm setting the LayoutParams of the CardView like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    height
            );
cardview.setLayoutParams(params4);
```

and create a new set of params for the Button

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params20 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
```

Add the align to bottom rule like this and then set these params to the LayoutParams of the Button

```
params20.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
search.setLayoutParams(params20);
```

In the end I add the Button to the CardView

```
cardView.addView(search);
```

But doing it like this the Button always stays at the top. When logging the CardViews and the parent of the Button the parent is as expected the current CardView

Log with 2 CardViews:

```
2021-01-27 10:15:45.843 7764-7764/lenno.plugin.smartplaner E/deine: cardview: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView{d12f026 VFE...CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1}........id: 1
2021-01-27 10:15:45.843 7764-7764/lenno.plugin.smartplaner E/deine1: parent: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView{d12f026 VFE...CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1}
2021-01-27 10:15:45.855 7764-7764/lenno.plugin.smartplaner E/deine: cardview: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView{ee5dc0a VFE...CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #2}........id: 2
2021-01-27 10:15:45.856 7764-7764/lenno.plugin.smartplaner E/deine1: parent: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView{ee5dc0a VFE...CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #2}
```

I already tried explicitly setting the anchor of params20 to the parent CardView like this

```
params20.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, cardView.getId());
```

which didn't work either. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in general (I just started creating Layouts programmatically) but I currently don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the initial problem was but I fixed it by using a ConstraintLayout for the Button and setting the topMargin to a fitting value.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params20 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params20.topMargin = 850;

search.setLayoutParams(params20);
cardView.addView(search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here an example. Read the comments for info.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        //CardView
        CardView cardview = new CardView(this);
        cardView.setId(1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1000);
        cardview.setLayoutParams(params4);

        //Button
        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("Button at the bottom");
        btn1.setId(2); //Only needed you wanna put another view close to this view. See below.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params20 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params20.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1 /* ID of cardView */); //This will cause this view (button) to be positioned at the bottom of parent view.
        
        //Add the Button to the CardView. Make sure to include the layout params too.
        cardview.addView(btn1, params20);
        
        //If you wanna add another view above btn1, here's how.
        Button btn2 = new Button(this);
        btn2.setText("I'm above button one");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params21 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params21.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, 2 /* ID of btn1 */);
        
        //Add btn2 to the CardView.
        cardview.addView(btn2, params21);
        
        //Main layout
        setContentView(cardview);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of thanks for your answer! Just tried it (didn't even know you could include params in the addView method so already learned something new :D), but somehow the Button is still located at the top.

Comment: It works just fine on my phone. Do you really need to use ```CardView```?, you can also use ```RelativeLayout```.

Comment: I'm displaying some data on the CardViews and want to give the user the option to delete each of them individually. If it works on your phone the problem for me might be some other layouts I have. I'm adding the CardView to another RelativeLayout which is contained in a ScrollView. Will look into that now

Comment: Ok I fixed it by using a ConstraintLayout for the Button setting the topMargin to a fitting value instead of using the RelativeLayout. Quite a weird bug. Anyways thanks for your help again!